# How to derive the demands from this rather bizarre utility?

Tags: demand

I have a rather bizarre utility function, which is neither differentiable nor quasi-concave
$$u(x_1,x_2)=\max\{\min\{x_1,2x_2\},\min\{2x_1,x_2\}\}$$
How to derive the demand function?

Comment: Refer to https://qr.ae/pvDf9H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to solve
$$
\max_{x_1, x_2} \left(\max\{\min\{x_1, 2 x_2\}, \min\{x_2, 2 x_1\}\}\right) \text{ s.t. } p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 \le m
$$

1. assume $x_1 \le 2 x_2$ and $x_2 \le 2 x_1$, then:
   $$
   u(x_1, x_2) = \max\{x_1, x_2\}.
   $$
   1.1 Now if $x_1 \ge x_2$ then this gives $u(x_1, x_2) = x_1$. We want to maximize this, so we put $x_1$ as high as possible, this gives $x_1 = 2 x_2$. Substituting into the budget constraint gives $x_2 = \frac{m}{2 p_1 + p_2}$ and $x_1 = \frac{2m}{2p_1 + p_2}$. Notice that indeed $x_2 \le 2 x_1$. The utility obtained is $u(x_1, x_2) = \frac{2m}{2p_1 + p_2}$.

   1.2 If $x_2 \ge x_1$ then this gives $u(x_1, x_2) = x_2$. We want to maximize this, so we put $x_2$ as high as possible. This gives $x_2 = 2 x_1$. Substituting into the budget constraint gives $x_1 = \frac{m}{p_1 + 2 p_2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{2m}{p_1 + 2 p_2}$. Then $u(x_1, x_2) = \frac{2m}{p_1 + 2 p_2}$.
2. if $x_1 \le 2 x_2$ and $2 x_1 \le x_2$ (notice that only the latter restriction is really necessary). Then:
   $$
   u(x_1, x_2) = \max\{x_1, 2x_1\} = 2 x_1
   $$
   Here, we want to make $x_1$ as large as possible. This gives $2 x_1 = x_2$. Substituting into the budget constraint gives $x_1 = \frac{m}{p_1 + 2 p_2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{2m}{p_1 + 2 p_2}$. The utility is given by $u(x_1, x_2) = \frac{2m}{p_1 + 2p_2}$.
3. if $2 x_2 \le x_1$ and $x_2 \le 2 x_1$. (notice that only hte first restriction is needed). Then
   $$
   u(x_1, x_2) = \max\{2 x_2, x_2\} = 2 x_2.
   $$
   Here, to make $x_2$ as large as possible, we will have $2 x_2 = x_1$. Then substituting into the budget constraint gives $x_2 = \frac{m}{2p_1 + p_2}$. and $x_1 = \frac{2m}{2p_1 + p_2}$. The utility is given by $u(x_1, x_2) = \frac{2m}{2p_1 + p_2}$.
4. If $2x_2 \le x_1$ and $2 x_1 \le x_2$. Then $2 x_2 \le x_1 \le 2 x_1 \le x_2$, which is possible only if $x_2 = 0$ and $x_1 = 0$, but this is never utility maximising.

Summarizing, we can choose between $u(x_1, x_2) = \frac{2m}{2p_1 + p_2}$ or $u(x_1, x_2) = \frac{2m}{p_1 + 2 p_2}$. The first will be the optimal choice (give more utility) if $p_1 < p_2$ the second will be optimal if $p_1 > p_2$. If $p_1 = p_2$ we are indifferent.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if you want to solve the problem:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} \max(f_1(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n),\ldots, f_m(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n))\end{eqnarray*}
Solve each of these $m$ problems:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} f_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) \end{eqnarray*}
where $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$

Assuming the conditions for the existence of these $m$ solutions hold (we can assume $f_j$ is continuous and $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$), let $(x_1^j,x_2^j,\dots, x_n^j)$ be one of the solutions to the problem
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} f_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) \end{eqnarray*}
so that $\max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} f_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)=f_j(x_1^j,x_2^j,\ldots, x_n^j)$

Proposition.
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} \max(f_1(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n),\ldots, f_m(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n))= \max_{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}} f_j(x_1^j,x_2^j,\ldots, x_n^j)\end{eqnarray*}

and

$j^*$ solves the problem
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}} f_j(x_1^j,x_2^j,\ldots, x_n^j)\end{eqnarray*}
if and only if $(x_1^{j^*},x_2^{j^*},\ldots, x_n^{j^*})$ solves the problem \begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} \max(f_1(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n),\ldots, f_m(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n))\end{eqnarray*}
Proof. Easy

We can now use this proposition and solve the given problem easily.
To summarise, we simply change the order of optimization:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C} \max_{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}} f_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) = \max_{j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}} \max_{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)\in C}  f_j(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Very clever @Amit +1!

Comment: @NicolasTorres Thank you :)